# convex optimization of an inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, control-theory, kalman-filter, linear-matrix-inequality

The motivation for this question is a relaxation of the well-known Riccati equation that will be introduced as a constraint in a convex optimization.

The variable is $P\succeq0$, and the constraint is
\begin{align}
P \succeq APA^T + Q - FPH^T(HPH^T+R)^{-1}HPF^T
\end{align}
where $R,Q\succ0$ and $A,F,H$ are arbitrary matrices.

We can organize the inequality as follows:
\begin{align}
P -APA^T - Q + FPH^T(HPH^T+R)^{-1}HPF^T\succeq 0
\end{align}
However, it is not possible to "linearize" it using the Schur complement since $HPH^T+R\succ0$.

Any ideas are welcomed.

**The standard approach fails:**
In order to represent the non-linear inequality, we can note that its LHS corresponds to the Schur complement of the matrix
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
P -APA^T - Q & FPH^T\\
HPF^T&  - (HPH^T+R)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This matrix is neither positive or negative definite since $- (HPH^T+R)$ is negative definite while the Schur complement is positive.

Comment: But you can consider $-(HPH^\top +R)$, right?

Comment: Not exactly. Based on my understanding of LMIs we should have $HPH^T+R\preceq0$. Can you please elaborate? @seaver

Comment: Can you provide more context regarding what you want to do? What is $A$? Is the same as $F$?

Comment: @KBS I added more explanations

Comment: The added details are not correct. The Schur complement does not apply there.

Comment: @KBS Schur complement is well defined for invertible $HPH^T+R$. Note for the minus in the (2,2) input of the matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Let us start with the Riccati equation

$$\begin{align}
APA^T-P + Q - FPH^T(HPH^T+R)^{-1}HPF^T=0.
\end{align}$$

We can now relax this expression as

$$\begin{align}
APA^T-P + Q - FPH^T(HPH^T+R)^{-1}HPF^T\succeq0.
\end{align}$$

which is clearly equivalent to the LMI

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
APA^T-P + Q & FPH^T\\HPF^T & HPH^T+R
\end{bmatrix}
\succeq0
\end{align}$$
by virtue of the Schur complement.

Now consider the optimization problem

$$\begin{align}
\max_{P\succeq0}\mathrm{trace}(P)\ \mathrm{such\ that}
\begin{bmatrix}
APA^T-P + Q & FPH^T\\HPF^T & HPH^T+R
\end{bmatrix}
\succeq0.
\end{align}$$

It can be shown that the optimal solution $P^*$ satisfies
$$\begin{align}
AP^*A^T-P^* + Q - FP^*H^T(HP^*H^T+R)^{-1}HP^*F^T=0.
\end{align}$$

*I am looking for a suitable reference. In the meantime, you can numerically verify that this is indeed the case.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please note that my question is regarding a relaxation of the Riccati equation in the opposite direction.

Comment: Then, it will not be a convex problem.

Comment: Counterexample then?

Comment: This is immediate from the structure of the problem but you can pick $a=f=h=1$ and we get that the inequality is equivalent to $p^2-qp-qr\ge0$. You can easily show that the feasibility set is disconnected, hence nonconvex.

Comment: The feasibility set is connected since $p\ge0$.